# find the two highest factors of a single number that are closest to each other

Tags: numbers

36-> 6*6 (not 9*4)

40-> 5*8 (not 10*4)

35-> 7*5
etc

I'm guessing something like:

```
candidate = input.square_root.round_to_nearest_int; 
while (true){
test = input/candidate;
 if (test.is_integer) return; 
else 
candidate.decrement;
}
```

Comment: The idea you gave is natural and clearly works. It isn't terribly efficient since it corresponds to a naïve trial-division approach to factorization. A better approach might be to first factor the number completely (using something more sophisticated than trial division) and then find the most balanced way to partition the factors into two groups.

Comment: I guess what I was asking was the starting point as square root is the correct point to begin.  But yes it is heuristic and inefficient; I'd only be inputting values in the low thousands at most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach does work.

If `n = ab` then `a <= sqrt(n) <= b`, hence if `a,b` are chosen so that `b-a` is minimized, it follows that `a` is the largest divisor of `n` which is less than or equal to the square root. The only tweak I would make to your pseudocode is to check the remainder and see if it is zero, rather than checking if the quotient is an integer. Something like (in Python):

```
import math

def closestDivisors(n):
    a = round(math.sqrt(n))
    while n%a > 0: a -= 1
    return a,n//a
```

For example,

```
>>> closestDivisors(36)
(6, 6)
>>> closestDivisors(40)
(5, 8)
>>> closestDivisors(1000003)
(1, 1000003)
```

(since the last input is prime).

Comment: Thanks, so my intuition was correct-- I just couldn't articulate it (minimizing the difference between the two factors is an elegant description of the problem).